# Options are missing in the Specials menu

Tags: interface

First of all, I just began exploring blender and I'm going through some tutorials right now.
I'm stuck on finding the options in the Specials menu after pressing <kbd>W</kbd>

[image: no options shown]
Can somebody help me out with this?
Thanks

Comment: I think you meant to go into edit mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options available by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> are context sensitive -- they differ depending on what mode you are in, i.e. Edit mode, Object mode, etc., and also what type of scenario you are in. For example, if you are in Edit mode with a mesh object, you will get different Special Options than if you are in Edit mode with a curve object.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I'm going to check that.

Comment: @Robin Let me know if you get stuck...just leave a comment here & we can help more. :)

Comment: That was it! I only had to change to edit mode. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to click the ["Solved" checkmark](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENMnU1ZmpBYjI4WlE/edit?usp=sharing) to let everyone know the question has been solved. :)